# Deploying ASP.NET Core solution with class library to Azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I'm working in VS2015 and have a ASP.NET Core solution with two projects - an API Web Project and a Class Library that holds all the data entities, context and Entity Framework migrations. The API project references the class library and all works well on my local machine.

I now want to deploy the solution to Azure and this is where I'm hitting the problem. If I right click on the API project and go through the Azure App Service publish wizard, on the Settings tab I expand Databases and the message is "No databases found for this project" - which I'm guessing is because it can't find a context as it's not in this project.

If I do the same on the CL project though, there is no Azure App Service deployment option, the only option is File System and clearly there's no option to create the database there either.

So, in summary, my question is how I can deploy this type of solution to Azure and have the database created and migrations applied?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the DB first in the azure and then try to publish your application through the wizard. The database is on your local machine and the application will work just fine on your local environment. But on the cloud you have to first create the database on Azure SQL. Then you need to get the SQL connection string from the portal and update your config file accordingly. Once this is done you can then publish your application from Visual Studio. Please note that the wizard will still not show you the databases, but the application, when configured properly will run fine.

Comment: Thanks. I already had created the Azure db, the issue is/was that when I use the Azure publish wizard in VS there was no option to set a connection string or run a migration. I kind of fixed it by changing the appsettings.json file to use "connectionStrings", then it picked those up. Still no way to run a migration that I can see, for now I have to use EF to generate a SQL command for the migration then manually run that against the Azure db.